# How to hide all my WebElements from my main test method using page object

Tags: c#, selenium

So i want to perform some tests using `selenium` on several webmail sites so i have build this :

```
public abstract class AbstractInboxPage<T> where T : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
{
   protected T Map
   {
        get { return new T(); }
   }

    public abstract void Login(string user, string pawwrod);

    public abstract void OpenContacts();

    public abstract void OpenRequireEmail();

    public abstract void OpenComposeMessageWindow();
}

public abstract class AbstractInboxPage<M, V> : AbstractInboxPage<M>
    where M : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
    where V : AbstractPageValidator<M>, new()
{
    public V Validate()
    {
        return new V();
    }
}
```

**Son**

```
public class GmailInboxPage : AbstractInboxPage
{
    public override void Login(string user, string pawwrod)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void OpenComposeMessageWindow()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void OpenContacts()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void OpenRequireEmail()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Driver**

```
public class WebDriver
    {
        private static IWebDriver _driver;
        private static WebDriverWait _webDriverWait;
        private static IJavaScriptExecutor _javaScriptExecutor;
        private static Actions _actions;
        private static BrowserType _browserType;

        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if (_driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method Start.");
                return _driver;
            }

            private set
            {
                _driver = value;
            }
        }

        public static WebDriverWait WebDriverWait
        {
            get
            {
                if (_webDriverWait == null || _driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver 'Driver' wait instance was not initialized. You should first call the method StartBrowser.");
                return _webDriverWait;
            }

            private set
            {
                _webDriverWait = value;
            }
        }

        public static IJavaScriptExecutor JavaScriptExecutor
        {
            get
            {
                if (_javaScriptExecutor == null || _driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver 'JavaScriptExecutor' instance was not initialized. You should first call the method StartBrowser.");
                return _javaScriptExecutor;
            }
        }

        public static Actions Actions
        {
            get
            {
                if (_actions == null || _driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver 'Actions' instance was not initialized. You should first call the method StartBrowser.");
                return _actions;
            }
        }

        public static BrowserType BrowserType
        {
            get
            {
                return _browserType;
            }
        }

        public static void StartBrowser(BrowserType browserType = BrowserType.Chrome, int defaultTimeOut = 120)
        {
            _browserType = browserType;
            switch (browserType)
            {
                case BrowserType.Firefox:
                    WebDriver.Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;

                case BrowserType.InternetExplorer:
                    break;

                case BrowserType.Chrome:

                    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
                    chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
                    chromeOptions.AddArguments("start-maximized");

                    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, chromeOptions);
                    WebDriver.Driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "chrome_driver"), chromeOptions);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            _webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(defaultTimeOut));
            _javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
            _actions = new Actions(_driver);
        }

        public static void StopBrowser()
        {
            _driver.Quit();
            _driver = null;
            _webDriverWait = null;
        }
    }
```

So i was thinking to create seperate class for example `AbstractInboxPageElementsMap` and another son (in my case `GmailInboxPageElementsMap`) and inside this i will locate all my elements using simple `get` but i want to hide this from my main so all the elements will be visible only from the son, in my case `GmailInboxPageElementsMap`.

```
public class AbstractPageEmenetsMap
{

}
```

And `page validator`

```
public class AbstractPageValidator<T> where T:AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
{

}
```

Now this is my `Gmail` implementation:

My page elements:

```
public class GmailInboxPageEmenetsMap : AbstractPageEmenetsMap
{
    public IWebElement ComposeButton
    {
        get { return WebDriver.WebDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[normalize-space(text())='COMPOSE']"))); }
    }
}
```

Some validator:

```
public class GmailInboxPageValidator:AbstractPageValidator<AbstractPageEmenetsMap>
{

}
```

Inbox page:

```
public class GmailInboxPage: AbstractInboxPage<GmailInboxPageEmenetsMap, GmailInboxPageValidator>
{
    public override void Login(string user, string pawwrod)
    {

    }

    public override void OpenComposeMessageWindow()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void OpenContacts()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void OpenRequireEmail()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Problems:

inside this class i got this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0311  The type 'GmailInboxPageValidator' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'V' in the generic type or method 'AbstractInboxPage'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'GmailInboxPageValidator' to
>   'AbstractPageValidator'.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep elements as private get properties in 'GmailInboxPage.cs' file. But your pursose is to keep elements in a separate file and to hide it from the main you can use 'partial class' concept.

Keep all the webelements in a separate 'patial class' of GmailInboxPage.cs file as private get properties.
In another partial class of GmailInboxPage.cs file can access these elements and you can hide it from the other files.

## File 1

You can keep your file name as 'GamilInboxElements' but the class name should be 'GmailInboxPage'. Refer the attached image

```
partial class GmailInboxPage
{
    private IWebElement ToButton { get { return xxxxx; }}
}
```

## File 2

```
 partial class  GmailInboxPage
    {
        public void setToAddress()
        {
            ToButton.SendKeys("xxxx");
        }
    }
```

[image]